# c# fujistu fi-6140 scanner Value does not fall within the expected range

Tags: c#, asp.net, window

I am developing one window application on C#. For that, I install driver WIA & get from "http://www.fujitsu.com/global/support/computing/peripheral/scanners/drivers/twain/v9211307.html"
- "Ft9l10bX5.exe".

My code:

```
class WIAScanner
    {
        const string wiaFormatBMP = "{B96B3CAB-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}";

        class WIA_DPS_DOCUMENT_HANDLING_SELECT
        {
            public const uint FEEDER = 0x00000001;
            public const uint FLATBED = 0x00000002;
        }

        class WIA_DPS_DOCUMENT_HANDLING_STATUS
        {
            public const uint FEED_READY = 0x00000001;
        }

        class WIA_PROPERTIES
        {
            public const uint WIA_RESERVED_FOR_NEW_PROPS = 1024;
            public const uint WIA_DIP_FIRST = 2;
            public const uint WIA_DPA_FIRST = WIA_DIP_FIRST + WIA_RESERVED_FOR_NEW_PROPS;
            public const uint WIA_DPC_FIRST = WIA_DPA_FIRST + WIA_RESERVED_FOR_NEW_PROPS;
            //
            // Scanner only device properties (DPS)
            //
            public const uint WIA_DPS_FIRST = WIA_DPC_FIRST + WIA_RESERVED_FOR_NEW_PROPS;
            public const uint WIA_DPS_DOCUMENT_HANDLING_STATUS = WIA_DPS_FIRST + 13;
            public const uint WIA_DPS_DOCUMENT_HANDLING_SELECT = WIA_DPS_FIRST + 14;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Use scanner to scan an image (with user selecting the scanner from a dialog).
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Scanned images.</returns>
        public static List<Image> Scan()
        {
            WIA.ICommonDialog dialog = new WIA.CommonDialog();
            WIA.Device device = dialog.ShowSelectDevice(WIA.WiaDeviceType.UnspecifiedDeviceType, true, false);

            if (device != null)
            {
                return Scan(device.DeviceID);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("You must select a device for scanning.");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Use scanner to scan an image (scanner is selected by its unique id).
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="scannerName"></param>
        /// <returns>Scanned images.</returns>
        public static List<Image> Scan(string scannerId)
        {
            List<Image> images = new List<Image>();

            bool hasMorePages = true;
            while (hasMorePages)
            {
                // select the correct scanner using the provided scannerId parameter
                WIA.DeviceManager manager = new WIA.DeviceManager();
                WIA.Device device = null;
                foreach (WIA.DeviceInfo info in manager.DeviceInfos)
                {
                    if (info.DeviceID == scannerId)
                    {
                        // connect to scanner
                        device = info.Connect();
                        break;
                    }
                }

                // device was not found
                if (device == null)
                {
                    // enumerate available devices
                    string availableDevices = "";
                    foreach (WIA.DeviceInfo info in manager.DeviceInfos)
                    {
                        availableDevices += info.DeviceID + "\n";
                    }

                    // show error with available devices
                    throw new Exception("The device with provided ID could not be found. Available Devices:\n" + availableDevices);
                }

                WIA.Item item = device.Items[1] as WIA.Item;

                try
                {
                    // scan image
                    WIA.ICommonDialog wiaCommonDialog = new WIA.CommonDialog();
                    WIA.ImageFile image = (WIA.ImageFile)wiaCommonDialog.ShowTransfer(item, wiaFormatBMP, false);

                    // save to temp file
                    string fileName = Path.GetTempFileName();

                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    throw exc;
                }
                finally
                {
                    item = null;

                    //determine if there are any more pages waiting
                    WIA.Property documentHandlingSelect = null;
                    WIA.Property documentHandlingStatus = null;

                    foreach (WIA.Property prop in device.Properties)
                    {
                        if (prop.PropertyID == WIA_PROPERTIES.WIA_DPS_DOCUMENT_HANDLING_SELECT)
                            documentHandlingSelect = prop;

                        if (prop.PropertyID == WIA_PROPERTIES.WIA_DPS_DOCUMENT_HANDLING_STATUS)
                            documentHandlingStatus = prop;
                    }

                    // assume there are no more pages
                    hasMorePages = false;

                    // may not exist on flatbed scanner but required for feeder
                    if (documentHandlingSelect != null)
                    {
                        // check for document feeder
                        if ((Convert.ToUInt32(documentHandlingSelect.get_Value()) & WIA_DPS_DOCUMENT_HANDLING_SELECT.FEEDER) != 0)
                        {
                            hasMorePages = ((Convert.ToUInt32(documentHandlingStatus.get_Value()) & WIA_DPS_DOCUMENT_HANDLING_STATUS.FEED_READY) != 0);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return images;
        }

    }
```

Now issue is: it's working fine on **"flatbed scanner"** But when i am trying with fijustu's  fi-6140 (sheetfed scanner). it's showing me error:

**"Value does not fall within the expected range."**  from this line: "WIA.ImageFile image = (WIA.ImageFile)wiaCommonDialog.ShowTransfer(item, wiaFormatBMP, false);"

So, let me know what configuration I am missing.

Answer (score 3):

I have run into the same problem with my fi-6310z.  It took me a while to figure out but it seems the problem is with the Pages property on the device (device property ID 3096).  It looks like it is set to 0 by default.  If you manually set it to 1 then ShowTransfer works fine.  I'm not sure if this will have an affect on how you determine if there are more pages or not because the method you have outlined doesn't work with my scanner (the document handling status is always 5).

Comment: I'm running into the same problem with a fi-6130Z, do you have the code for the fix?

Comment: This Issue and this solution applies too for the epson workforce ds-30

Comment: this is the code that worked for me  SetDeviceProperty(device, "3096", 1);                                        private void SetDeviceProperty(IDevice item, object property, object value)
        {
            WIA.Property aProperty = item.Properties.get_Item(ref property);
            aProperty.set_Value(ref value);
        }

Comment: Same here with a "Brother DCP-7045N". Setting Page = 1 will only scan the first page via feeder though. But in my use case that's still better than nothing.

Comment: I used the code mentioned by @Boanerge but the problem did not resolve

Comment: @HasanShouman I mentioned that my solution worked for the scanner workforce ds-30. Is your device a workforce ds-30 ?

Answer (score 0):

Tried SetDeviceProperty as mentioned by  "Boanerge" and to work consistently, first deleted the old file, used thread.sleep(2000); before and after scanning and prior to saving the file, it worked.